# Index and newcommand

Tags: indexing

I have a short question about indexing.

Is it possible that latex automatically creates an entry in the index, 
when I first use a notation fixed by `\newcommand`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you give an example? In general, introducing notation into your publications by `\newcommand` is a good idea especially because it allows to bind index or glossary entries to it.

Comment: Dear S.Lehmke, that is exactly what i intended to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own command (called `\notation` here) to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{mathabx} %For the \rip symbol
\newcommand\notation[2]{\newcommand{#1}{#2}{\index{#2}}}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\notation{\tomb}{$\rip$}
After shooing them, I buried the bodies in a \tomb.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Note that this creates the index entry when the command is defined, rather than upon its first use.

Comment: Thank you, though I can not yet upvote;)

Comment: I'd use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work with amsbook.

Comment: @user12882: for amsbook simply delete (or comment out) the line `\usepackage{makeidx}`.

Comment: No I tried this as well - no error message, but no index in pdf file as well;(

Comment: @user12882 --- `amsbook` with `\usepackage{makeidx}` removed works for me.

Comment: @egreg --- indeed. Right as usual!